# storing data contains special characters in orientdb

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, graph-databases, orientdb

WE are using Orient DB to store our data. In that we are storing that using Ruby hashes. But if any special characters come in hash values the it breaks hash structure and causes error whiles storing.
WE need some help on how we can escape hash values so that special character get converted into constants.

we are passing following hash to orient db and it causes error because addressLine1 contain special characters which breaks JSON format.

```
{
  "addressLine1" =>"my address`~!@\#$%^&*()_ +=-{}|[]:\"';<>?/.,",
  "addressLine2"=>"india",
  "city"=>"bangalore",
}
```

One thing we can do is that escape all strings in hash and then pass it to orient db and again while reading we will unescape this. Please give optimal solution.

Comment: Could you post the command you executed that gives you the error?

Comment: Have you tried with OrientDB v1.7.8 or are you using an older version?

Comment: Yes we are tried 1.7.8 also. we are using 1.6 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Lvca. After upgrading orientdb to 1.7.8 version we are able to resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

Trying this works:

```
insert into V content {
  "addressLine1" : "my address`~!@\#$%^&*()_ +=-{}|[]:\"';<>?/.,",
  "addressLine2":"india",
  "city" : "bangalore"
}
```

Comment: It is working from orient db console. But we are using Ofunctions. I thing problem is not with orient but it is at javascript code that written in Ofunction. We pass data to orient through REST apis using NET http. Insert data is breaking in Ofunction where we do JSON stringify operation. Following solution is worked for us